# How to check the Spark version

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera-cdh

as titled, how do I know which version of spark has been installed in the CentOS?

The current system has installed cdh5.1.0.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

If you use Spark-Shell, it appears in the banner at the start.

Programatically, `SparkContext.version` can be used.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm getting `<property object at 0x7f8d2afb2998>` in python shell

Comment: @PikoMonde version is a property on the SparkContext class so you just need to call it on an **instance** of that class.

Comment: Yep, I just realize that. I think, for someone like me, who is new on python and spark, a complete code (programatically) is helpful. Here I wrote the complete code [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60523639/9183891)

Comment: I am running a different version of pyspark and spark core, is there a way to print the version of spark core? everything so far gives the version of pyspark

Answer (score 41):

Open Spark shell Terminal, run sc.version

[image]

Answer (score 38):

You can use spark-submit command:
`spark-submit --version`

Answer (score 34):

## In Spark 2.x program/shell,

use the

```
spark.version
```

Where `spark` variable is of `SparkSession` object

### Using the console logs at the start of `spark-shell`

```
[root@bdhost001 ~]$ spark-shell
Setting the default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel).
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.2.0
      /_/
```

---

## Without entering into code/shell

### `spark-shell --version`

```
[root@bdhost001 ~]$ spark-shell --version
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.2.0
      /_/
                        
Type --help for more information.
```

### `spark-submit --version`

```
[root@bdhost001 ~]$ spark-submit --version
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.2.0
      /_/
                        
Type --help for more information.
```

Comment: sometime it will be `spark2-shell --version` or `spark2-submit --version`

Answer (score 16):

If you are using Databricks and talking to a notebook, just run :

```
spark.version
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using pyspark, the spark version being used can be seen beside the bold Spark logo as shown below:

```
manoj@hadoop-host:~$ pyspark
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel).

Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.6.0
      /_/

Using Python version 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015 17:58:13)
SparkContext available as sc, HiveContext available as sqlContext.
>>>
```

If you want to get the spark version explicitly, you can use version method of SparkContext as shown below:

```
>>>
>>> sc.version
u'1.6.0'
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

Which ever shell command you use either spark-shell or pyspark, it will land on a Spark Logo with a version name beside it.

$ pyspark
$ Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, May 22 2015, 08:34:51)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-15)] on linux2
............
...........
Welcome to
     version 1.3.0

Answer (score 4):

If you are on **Zeppelin notebook** you can run:

```
sc.version
```

to know the scala version as well you can ran:

```
util.Properties.versionString
```

Answer (score 4):

use below to get the spark version

```
spark-submit --version
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to print the version programmatically use

```
 from pyspark.sql import SparkSession 

 spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").getOrCreate() 
 print(spark.sparkContext.version)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run it programatically using `python` script

You can use this `script.py`:

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark import SQLContext, SparkConf

sc_conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext(conf=sc_conf)
print(sc.version)
```

run it with `python script.py` or `python3 script.py`

---

This above script is also works on python shell.

---

Using `print(sc.version)` directly on the python script won't work. If you run it directly, you will get this error:`NameError: name 'sc' is not defined`.

Comment: This should be `sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=sc_conf)`. _Not_ like this: `sc = SparkContext(conf=sc_conf)`!

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
import util.Properties.versionString
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val spark = SparkSession
  .builder
  .appName("my_app")
  .master("local[6]")
  .getOrCreate()
println("Spark Version: " + spark.version)
println("Scala Version: " + versionString)
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers here requires initializing a sparksession. This answer provide a way to statically infer the version from library.

```
ammonites@ org.apache.spark.SPARK_VERSION
res4: String = "2.4.5"
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

If like me, one is running spark inside a docker container and has little means for the spark-shell, one can run jupyter notebook, build `SparkContext` object called `sc` in the jupyter notebook, and call the version as shown in the codes below:

```
docker run -p 8888:8888 jupyter/pyspark-notebook ##in the shell where docker is installed

import pyspark
sc = pyspark.SparkContext('local[*]')
sc.version
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to print the Spark's version on the shell, following solution work.

```
SPARK_VERSION=$(spark-shell --version &> tmp.data ; grep version tmp.data | head -1 | awk '{print $NF}';rm tmp.data)
echo $SPARK_VERSION
```

Answer (score -1):

Non-interactive way, that I am using for AWS EMR proper PySpark version installation:

```
# pip3 install pyspark==$(spark-submit --version 2>&1| grep -m 1  -Eo "([0-9]{1,}\.)+[0-9]{1,}") 
Collecting pyspark==2.4.4
```

solution:

```
#  spark-shell --version 2>&1| grep -m 1  -Eo "([0-9]{1,}\.)+[0-9]{1,}"
2.4.4
```

solution:

```
# spark-submit --version 2>&1| grep -m 1  -Eo "([0-9]{1,}\.)+[0-9]{1,}"
2.4.4
```

Comment: It’s using grep and pipe, while non other answer is using non-interactive approach without cache the output in file.There is example how to use it with pip install