# What version of Apache spark is used in my IBM Analytics for Apache Spark for IBM Cloud service?

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud

I saw an email indicating the sunset of support for 1.6 apache spark within IBM Cloud.  I am pretty sure my version is 2.x, but I wanted to confirm.  I couldn't find anywhere in the UI that indicated the version, and the bx cli command that I thought would show it didn't.

```
[chrisr@oc5287453221 ~]$ bx service show "Apache Spark-bc"
Invoking 'cf service Apache Spark-bc'...


Service instance: Apache Spark-bc
Service: spark
Bound apps: 
Tags: 
Plan: ibm.SparkService.PayGoPersonal
Description: IBM Analytics for Apache Spark for IBM Cloud.
Documentation url: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/AnalyticsforApacheSpark/index.html
Dashboard: https://spark-dashboard.ng.bluemix.net/dashboard

Last Operation
Status: create succeeded
Message: 
Started: 2018-01-22T16:08:46Z
Updated: 2018-01-22T16:08:46Z
```

How do I determine the version of spark that I am using?  Also, I tried going to the "Dashboard" URL from above, and I got an "Internal Server Error" message after logging in.

The information found on [How to check the Spark version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29689960/how-to-check-the-spark-version) doesn't seem to help, because it seems to be related to locally installed spark instances.  I need to find out the information from the IBM Cloud (ie. Bluemix) using either the UI or the bluemix CLI.  Other possibilities would be running some command from a Jupyter Notebook in iPython running in Data Science Experience (part of IBM Cloud).

Comment: I updated my question to clarify that the instance of spark is running in the IBM Cloud, and I am looking to find out the version via the IBM Cloud (ie. Bluemix) UI or CLI, or from DSX.

Comment: The Spark service itself is not version specific. To find out whether or not you need to migrate you need to inspect the apps/tools that utilize the service. For example if you've created notebooks in DSX you associated them with a kernel that was bound to a specific Spark version and you'd need to open each notebook to find out which Spark version they are utilizing.

Comment: I see, thanks.  All of my notebooks are bound to Spark 2.0.

Comment: Can you answer your own question then @ChrisRatcliffe instead of leaving it open.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was given by ptitzler above, just adding an answer as requested by the email I was sent.

> The Spark service itself is not version specific. To find out whether
>   or not you need to migrate you need to inspect the apps/tools that
>   utilize the service. For example if you've created notebooks in DSX
>   you associated them with a kernel that was bound to a specific Spark
>   version and you'd need to open each notebook to find out which Spark
>   version they are utilizing. – ptitzler Jan 31 at 16:32