# Query hive database using hive context created on spark 2.3.0

Tags: apache-spark, hivecontext

I am able to create a hive context programmatically on spark 1.6.0 using :

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkTest").setMaster("local")
val sc=new SparkContext(conf)
val hc = new HiveContext(sc)
val actualRecordCountHC = hc.sql("select count(*) from hiveorc_replica.appointment")
```

This is working fine for me.
In the same way, I want to create a hive context on spark 2.3.0 but when running the program, it throws the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 
Table or view not found: `hiveorc_replica`.`appointment`; line 1 pos 21;
'Aggregate [unresolvedalias(count(1), None)]
    'UnresolvedRelation `hiveorc_replica`.`appointment`
```

I know that HiveContext(sc) has been deprecated in 2.3.0 but when run these as commands on spark-shell, they are also giving results. Also, I want to make the program generic for both versions of spark. Can someone please suggest some way of querying hive tables directly without using the hive database file names  ?

Following is the hive-site.xml I am using to connect remotely-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--Autogenerated by Cloudera Manager-->
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
    <value>thrift://fqdn:9083</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.client.socket.timeout</name>
    <value>300</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
    <value>/user/hive/warehouse</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.warehouse.subdir.inherit.perms</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.auto.convert.join</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask.size</name>
    <value>20971520</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.optimize.bucketmapjoin.sortedmerge</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.smbjoin.cache.rows</name>
    <value>10000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.server2.logging.operation.enabled</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.server2.logging.operation.log.location</name>
    <value>/var/log/hive/operation_logs</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapred.reduce.tasks</name>
    <value>-1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer</name>
    <value>67108864</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.exec.copyfile.maxsize</name>
    <value>33554432</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.exec.reducers.max</name>
    <value>1099</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.vectorized.groupby.checkinterval</name>
    <value>4096</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.vectorized.groupby.flush.percent</name>
    <value>0.1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.compute.query.using.stats</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.vectorized.execution.enabled</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.vectorized.execution.reduce.enabled</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.merge.mapfiles</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.merge.mapredfiles</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.cbo.enable</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.fetch.task.conversion</name>
    <value>minimal</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.fetch.task.conversion.threshold</name>
    <value>268435456</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.limit.pushdown.memory.usage</name>
    <value>0.1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.merge.sparkfiles</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize</name>
    <value>16777216</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.merge.size.per.task</name>
    <value>268435456</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.optimize.reducededuplication</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.optimize.reducededuplication.min.reducer</name>
    <value>4</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.map.aggr</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.map.aggr.hash.percentmemory</name>
    <value>0.5</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.optimize.sort.dynamic.partition</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.execution.engine</name>
    <value>mr</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>spark.executor.memory</name>
    <value>268435456</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>spark.driver.memory</name>
    <value>268435456</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>spark.executor.cores</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead</name>
    <value>26</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead</name>
    <value>26</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors</name>
    <value>2147483647</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.execute.setugi</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.support.concurrency</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>fqdn</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.zookeeper.client.port</name>
    <value>2181</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.zookeeper.namespace</name>
    <value>hive_zookeeper_namespace_CD-HIVE-WAyDdBlP</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.cluster.delegation.token.store.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.MemoryTokenStore</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.server2.enable.doAs</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.sasl.enabled</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.kerberos.principal</name>
    <value>hive/_HOST@EXAMPLE.COM</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.server2.authentication.kerberos.principal</name>
    <value>hive/_HOST@EXAMPLE.COM</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>spark.shuffle.service.enabled</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.server2.authentication</name>
    <value>LDAP</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Here, fqdn is being replaced by the host hdfs FQDN during run time and is running perfectly for spark 1.6.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In spark 2.x.x you need to use `enableHiveSupport()` when creating SparkSession

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("Example")
      .master("local")
      .config("hive.metastore.uris","thrift://B:PortNumber")
      .enableHiveSupport()                // <---- This line here
      .getOrCreate()
```

And if you want generic - I think you just need to create SparkContext and HiveContext separately:

```
if (sparkVersion <= 2.x.x) {
    // create the old way
}
else 
{
   //create spark session and then get SparkContext and HiveContext from it.
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29689960/how-to-check-the-spark-version) you can find how to know spark version programmatically

Comment: i believe its searching the database locally instead of searching on remote hdfs cluster and since its unable to get it, its throwing the Table or view not found exception. Any comments ? @Vladislav Varslavans. I am also adding the hive-site.xml in the question.

Comment: creating spark session for spark2 did the job. On seeing the logs, I found that somehow it was unable to get the value of hive.metastore.uri from hive-site.xml and setting it through spark-session was the answer. However, I still have a doubt as to why is it not able to get value of hive.metastore.uri for running remotely when its able to get the file from resources ?

Comment: Unfortunately i can't answer that. The only thing I see is possible typo `hive.metastore.uris`. In your comment I see `uri` in singular (however in example code it's correct).